# React function inside a fetching

Tags: reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I'm listing a table with lot of rows, and i would like to use a new function in each row dependly on the {transaction.to_address} value

I want to use useeffect() function inside a fetching function, but i've got this error message:
Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
I have tried many solution i found here, i've spent almost a whole day, but i'm not smart enough to fix it.

```
export default function Transactions({user}){
    
    const Web3Api = useMoralisWeb3Api()
    const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState()
    const BASE_URL = "https://bscscan.com/tx/"


    const fetchTransactions = async () => {
        const data = await Web3Api.account.getTransactions({
            chain: "bsc",
            address: user.get('wallet2')
        })
        if(data) {
            setTransactions(data.result)
        }
    }
   

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTransactions()
    }, [])

    return(
            <TableContainer>
            <Table variant='simple'>
                <TableCaption>TRANSACTIONS</TableCaption>
                <Thead>
                <Tr>
                    <Th>#</Th>
                    <Th>TYPE</Th>
                    <Th>GAS</Th>
                    <Th>VALUE</Th>
                    <Th>4</Th>
                    <Th>5</Th>
                    <Th>Value</Th>
                 </Tr>
                </Thead>
                <Tbody>
                {transactions && transactions.map(transaction => (
                  transaction.value >= 1 ?    
                    <Tr key={transaction.hash}>
                        <Th><Link href={`${BASE_URL}${transaction.hash}`} isExternal> {transaction.nonce}</Link></Th>    
                        <Th>TRANS{transaction.block_timestamp}</Th>
                        <Th>{transaction.receipt_gas_used * Moralis.Units.FromWei(transaction.gas_price)} BNB</Th>
                        <Th>{Moralis.Units.FromWei(transaction.value)} BNB</Th>
                       <Th>{transaction.block_timestamp}</Th>
                       <Th>
                   {
                    useEffect(() => {
                        const url = "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address={transaction.to_address}&apikey=EEFI13SBM525DZ5ZNMBZHFEMVIT39DZA26";
                    
                        const fetchData = async () => {
                            const response = await fetch(url)
                            const json = await response.json()

                        }
                        fetchData()
                    }, [])
                   }
                        </Th>
                        <Th><Link href={`${BASE_URL}${transaction.hash}`} isExternal> {transaction.hash}</Link></Th>  
                    </Tr>                     
                 : null))} 
                </Tbody>
            </Table>
            </TableContainer>
    )
}
```

This is similar to my problem, but not working for me

[Uncaught Invariant Violation: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622768/uncaught-invariant-violation-rendered-more-hooks-than-during-the-previous-rende)

Comment: useEffect() has to be positioned before the return of your function. You can call your asynchronous function and store your data in your function (your component) and after map on your result to generate your rendering

Comment: Thanks Fred. Sorry i'm really beginner, i understand only your first sentece. Can you show me the second part, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i don't think it's a good practice to use useEffect hook in the middle of html code, useEffect should be always called before return. [Read more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Secondly you should think if this approach is any good as fetching data in a for cycle might cause much load on your server (it depends how many transactions you have and how many requests you are sending every-time).

useEffect is used to fetch data when the page loads or you can place parameters to it so it runs the code again when the parameters change. You can fetch data without useEffect.

As i cannot replicate your code please try running this on your own.

```
export default function Transactions({ user }) {
  const Web3Api = useMoralisWeb3Api();
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState();
  const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState();
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState(false);
  const BASE_URL = "https://bscscan.com/tx/";

  const fetchTransactions = async () => {
    const data = await Web3Api.account.getTransactions({
      chain: "bsc",
      address: user.get("wallet2"),
    });
    if (data) {
      setTransactions(data.result);
      setFinished(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (finished && transactions) {
      let list = [];
      Promise.all(
        transactions.map(async (transaction) => {
          const API = `https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=${transaction.to_address}&apikey=EEFI13SBM525DZ5ZNMBZHFEMVIT39DZA26`;
          const data = await fetch(API);
          if (data) {
            list.push(data);
          }
        })
      );
      setTransaction(list);
      setFinished(true);
    }
  }, [finished]);

  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <Table variant="simple">
        <TableCaption>TRANSACTIONS</TableCaption>
        <Thead>
          <Tr>
            <Th>#</Th>
            <Th>TYPE</Th>
            <Th>GAS</Th>
            <Th>VALUE</Th>
            <Th>4</Th>
            <Th>5</Th>
            <Th>Value</Th>
          </Tr>
        </Thead>
        <Tbody>
          {transactions &&
            transactions.map((transaction, index) =>
              transaction.value >= 1 ? (
                <Tr key={transaction.hash}>
                  <Th>
                    <Link href={`${BASE_URL}${transaction.hash}`} isExternal>
                      {" "}
                      {transaction.nonce}
                    </Link>
                  </Th>
                  <Th>TRANS{transaction.block_timestamp}</Th>
                  <Th>
                    {transaction.receipt_gas_used *
                      Moralis.Units.FromWei(transaction.gas_price)}{" "}
                    BNB
                  </Th>
                  <Th>{Moralis.Units.FromWei(transaction.value)} BNB</Th>
                  <Th>{transaction.block_timestamp}</Th>
                  <Th>{transaction[index].ContractName}</Th>
                  <Th>
                    <Link href={`${BASE_URL}${transaction.hash}`} isExternal>
                      {" "}
                      {transaction.hash}
                    </Link>
                  </Th>
                </Tr>
              ) : null
            )}
        </Tbody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tomas, the previous error message is finally gone, but now i've got another one:

"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."...

I have noticed the ${address} you used in link, is that the "address: user.get("wallet2")"?
I would like to get the value of {transaction.to_address} into the link, and show that result in the table.

Comment: Could you please instead of `return json` write `console.log(json)` and see what it prints to your console? From your error message I think that fetch is working and you just need to handle your data. In the function I'm just using one word address but if you look closely I'm sending to function transacton.to_address `fetchData(transaction.to_address)}`

Comment: I have tried it, but i've got same error message, and the console got crazy, but no "json" there....
address: That's great, sorry, i thought the issue is because of missunderstanding :)

Comment: The response you are getting is probably something similar to this `{firstName: "Name",  lastName: "LastName", value: "someValue"}`. To put this into html you should write something like this : `<Th>{let data = fetchData(transaction.to_address) data.value}</Th>`. By replacing `return json` with `console.log(json)` you don't fix the code, but you should see the response object in the console and its values so you can choose the right one for you.

Comment: This is what is see: https://i.postimg.cc/4yrqqBWv/Untitled.png

Comment: Thats good, click on the object and see what the value is.

Comment: YEAAAH. Indeed, The value is there! :) I'm sorry. How can i get rid of the error messages? (I will need the value of ContractName)

Comment: <Th>{let data = fetchData(transaction.to_address) data.ContractName}</Th>
I got syntax error with this ("data" + the last "}" are red)

Comment: It is probably because you can console.log the json but you can't directly return it as it return's a promise. You need to use useState and store it there or something.

Comment: Can i kindly ask you to show an example? I'm not a programmer just working in BI and need only 1 app for myself, but i'm struggling with it since monday morning and i'm really close to giving up. :( Huge respect for you all who understand javascript/react etc.

Comment: @datafetcher I have edited the code, try to run it now.

Comment: The main table is empty (shows only the header), and the console is empty:
https://i.postimg.cc/Nj1ksxx0/editedversion.png

Comment: Interesting, it looks like you are not getting any transactions data as the table is empty. Might be something wrong with your first fetch.

Comment: Yes, i'm so mad :( The original fetch is working well.
https://i.postimg.cc/QdmVJ6gw/original.png

Answer (score 0):

I tried without testing it, so let me know :

```
export default function Transactions({user}){
    
    const Web3Api = useMoralisWeb3Api()
    const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState(null)
    const [transactionsAddress,setTransactionsAddress]= useState(null)
    const BASE_URL = "https://bscscan.com/tx/"


    const fetchTransactions = async () => {
        const data = await Web3Api.account.getTransactions({
            chain: "bsc",
            address: user.get('wallet2')
        })
        if(data) {
            setTransactions(data.result)
        }
    }
    const fetchData = useCallBack(async (myUrl) => {
        const response = await fetch(myUrl)
        const json = await response.json()
        return json},
        []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTransactions()
    }, [])

    
    useEffect(() => {
        transactions ?? (async ()=>{
        let url=""
        const fetchTransationsAddress= await Promise.all(transactions.map(async (transaction) => {
            url = `https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=${transaction.to_address}&apikey=EEFI13SBM525DZ5ZNMBZHFEMVIT39DZA26`;
            return await fetchData(url);
             
        }));
        setTransactionsAddress(fetchTransationsAddress);
    })
    }, [transactions])

    return(
            <TableContainer>
            <Table variant='simple'>
                <TableCaption>TRANSACTIONS</TableCaption>
                <Thead>
                <Tr>
                    <Th>#</Th>
                    <Th>TYPE</Th>
                    <Th>GAS</Th>
                    <Th>VALUE</Th>
                    <Th>4</Th>
                    <Th>5</Th>
                    <Th>Value</Th>
                 </Tr>
                </Thead>
                <Tbody>
                {transactions && transactions.map((transaction,index) => (
                  transaction.value >= 1 ?    
                    <Tr key={transaction.hash}>
                        <Th><Link href={`${BASE_URL}${transaction.hash}`} isExternal> {transaction.nonce}</Link></Th>    
                        <Th>TRANS{transaction.block_timestamp}</Th>
                        <Th>{transaction.receipt_gas_used * Moralis.Units.FromWei(transaction.gas_price)} BNB</Th>
                        <Th>{Moralis.Units.FromWei(transaction.value)} BNB</Th>
                       <Th>{transaction.block_timestamp}</Th>
                       <Th>
                        {
                        //map here in your address, for example
                        transactionsAddress[index] && transactionsAddress[index].map((address) =>{return(<Td>{address}</Td>)})}
                        </Th>
                        <Th><Link href={`${BASE_URL}${transaction.hash}`} isExternal> {transaction.hash}</Link></Th>  
                    </Tr>                     
                 : null))} 
                </Tbody>
            </Table>
            </TableContainer>
    )
}
```

For your tests, simplify your code  like this:

```
       export default function Transactions({user}){
            
            const Web3Api = useMoralisWeb3Api()
            const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState(null)
            const [transactionsAddress,setTransactionsAddress]= useState(null)
            const BASE_URL = "https://bscscan.com/tx/"
        
        
            const fetchTransactions = async () => {
                console.log('fetchTransactions');
                const data = await Web3Api.account.getTransactions({
                    chain: "bsc",
                    address: user.get('wallet2')
                })
                if(data) {
                    setTransactions(data.result)
                }
            }
            const fetchData = useCallBack(async (myUrl) => {
                console.log('callback fetchdata')
                const response = await fetch(myUrl)
                const json = await response.json()
                return json},
                []);
        
            useEffect(() => {
                console.log('useEffect 1');
                fetchTransactions()
            }, [])

            
            useEffect(() => {
                console.log('useEffect 2');
                if (transactions!==null){
                  (async ()=>{
                   let url="";
                   console.log('async function inside useEffect2')
                   const fetchTransationsAddress= await Promise.all(transactions.map(async (transaction) => {
                    url = `https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=${transaction.to_address}&apikey=EEFI13SBM525DZ5ZNMBZHFEMVIT39DZA26`;
                    return await fetchData(url);
                     
                }));
                setTransactionsAddress(fetchTransationsAddress);
  })();
  }}, [transactions,fetchData])
    
        console.log(transactions)    
        console.log(transactionsAddress)
    
            return(<div>Go to your console</div>
    )}
```

And know try to find what's wrong, you can add some console.log("what you want") to understand. You also need to check if your API calls are returning data (depending on your subscription your are possibly limited)

Comment: i added async keyword in the code

Comment: No more error message, but the value in the list is still the old one (transaction.to_address) instead of the result.

Comment: I tried console.log(json) too but no reaction in consoloe

Comment: This also not giving any result:"{   transactionsAddress[index] && transactionsAddress[index].map((result) => result.ContractName)}

Do you have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The map function return a new array: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). If you want to display in the console what you get for each iteration with map, you can do something like this : `myArray.map( (currentValue)=>console.log(currentValue))`. If you want to store the value in a new Array  just write `const newArray =myArray.map((currentValue)=>console.log(currentValue))`

Comment: The console still empty using this code: ''
 {transactionsAddress[index] && transactionsAddress[index].map( (currentValue)=>console.log(currentValue.ContractName))} '' is this what you meant?

Comment: It's quite difficult to help you... I don't know what is working. Can you make a new file and remove all in the return of your function. (You can just put instead `return(<div>Test</div>`) Just before return function add `console.log (transactions)` and `console.log(transactionsAddress)` .

Comment: const fetchData = useCallback(async (myUrl) => {
        const response = await fetch(myUrl)
        const json = await response.json()
        console.log (transactions)
        console.log(transactionsAddress)
        return(<div>Test</div>) },
        []);.......................Console is still empty :(

Comment: I just tried your edited verison, was some syntax error but now it works perfectly, but now i see it's only the "main datas" from the table :( 
https://i.postimg.cc/4NgPHMFg/asdasdas.png

Comment: This is an example for the result (ContractName which i need)
https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955&apikey=EEFI13SBM525DZ5ZNMBZHFEMVIT39DZA26 . and this in the console: https://i.postimg.cc/Vk5KztVr/console.png

Comment: i modified the simplified code, there was a problem with the callback function call

Comment: "url is not defined" https://i.postimg.cc/1XypTXtM/urldeg.png 
But Tomas helped me with an other solution which is almost works, only there is a small issue, could you please take a look at it? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758541/why-typing-url-manually-doesnt-cause-cors-error

Comment: copy paste error...You just have to add a declaration let url=""; . i modified the code

Comment: I've got same issue like in Tomas's solution :( https://i.postimg.cc/mrZZKP1p/err.png

Comment: Thank you very much Fred! Your Solution is works too, the problem is limited calls on the server side!