# router.query returning undefined in nextjs

Tags: next.js

On the initial loading of the Edit page, the query is returning as 'undefined' instead of the expected result. I am using client-side fetching and not using SSG or SSR. The 'Edit' page is located in the '/src/pages/solution/[id]/edit' directory.

Anyone, please tell me how I can fetch data using `useDocument` hook?

I tried to use `isReady` like this, but it's just showing a blank screen:

```
const SolutionEditForm = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(INITIAL_STATE)
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id, isReady } = router.query

  if (!isReady) return null

  const { document } = useDocument("solutions", id)


  useEffect(() => {
    if (document) {
      setFormData(document)
    }
  }, [document])

  return (
    // JSX CODE
  )
}
```

My code:

```
const SolutionEditForm = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(INITIAL_STATE)
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query

  console.log(id) // return undefined

  const { document } = useDocument("solutions", id) // throws error because id is undefined


  useEffect(() => {
    if (document) {
      setFormData(document)
    }
  }, [document])

  return (
    // JSX CODE
  )
}

export default SolutionEditForm
```

Anyone, please help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isReady` is part of the [router object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object), not of `router.query`

Try `router.isReady` to validate if the router is already loaded.

Comment: After adding isReady, now it's throwing this error message: `Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

Comment: @r121 this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65558219/1133816

Comment: This thread didn't solve my problem because I can't call the useDocument hook after the if check(conditionally)