# Getting Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I load my Nextjs page, I get this error message: *"Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render."*

If I add that `if (!router.isReady) return null` after the `useEffect` code, the page does not have access to the `solutionId` on the initial load, causing an error for the `useDocument` hook, which requires the `solutionId` to fetch the document from the database.

Therefore, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622768/uncaught-invariant-violation-rendered-more-hooks-than-during-the-previous-rende) does not address my issue.

Anyone, please help me with this issue!

My code:

```
const SolutionEditForm = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(INITIAL_STATE)
  const router = useRouter()
  const { solutionId } = router.query

  if (!router.isReady) return null

  const { document } = useDocument("solutions", solutionId)
  const { updateDocument, response } = useFirestore("solutions")

  useEffect(() => {
    if (document) {
      setFormData(document)
    }
  }, [document])

  return (
    <div>
     // JSX code
    </div>
  )
}
```

useDocument hook:

```
export const useDocument = (c, id) => {
  const [document, setDocument] = useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const ref = doc(db, c, id)
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      ref,
      (snapshot) => {
        setIsLoading(false)
        if (snapshot.data()) {
          setDocument({ ...snapshot.data(), id: snapshot.id })
          setError(null)
        } else {
          setError("No such document exists")
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err.message)
        setIsLoading(false)
        setError("failed to get document")
      }
    )
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [c, id])

  return { document, isLoading, error }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a hook, `useEffect`, your custom `useDocument`, or any other after a condition. The condition in your case is this early return `if (!router.isReady) returns null`. As you can read on [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns...

Just remove that `if (!router.isReady) returns null` from `SolutionEditForm` and change `useDocument` as below.

```js
export const useDocument = (c, id) => {
  const [document, setDocument] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!id) return; // if there is no id, do nothing 
    const ref = doc(db, c, id);
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      ref,
      (snapshot) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (snapshot.data()) {
          setDocument({ ...snapshot.data(), id: snapshot.id });
          setError(null);
        } else {
          setError("No such document exists");
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError("failed to get document");
      }
    );
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [c, id]);

  return { document, isLoading, error };
};
```

Comment: your solution is the simplest one. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `if (!router.isReady) return null` statement caused the function to end early, and subsequent hooks are not executed.

You need to restructure your hooks such that none of them are conditional:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState(INITIAL_STATE)
  const router = useRouter()
  const { solutionId } = router.query


  const { document } = useDocument("solutions", solutionId, router.isReady) // pass a flag to disable until ready
  const { updateDocument, response } = useFirestore("solutions")

  useEffect(() => {
    if (document) {
      setFormData(document)
    }
  }, [document])

// Move this to after the hooks.
  if (!router.isReady) return null
```

and then to make `useDocument` avoid sending extra calls:

```
export const useDocument = (c, id, enabled) => {
```

and updated the effect with a check:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!enabled) return;
    const ref = doc(db, c, id)
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      ref,
      (snapshot) => {
        setIsLoading(false)
        if (snapshot.data()) {
          setDocument({ ...snapshot.data(), id: snapshot.id })
          setError(null)
        } else {
          setError("No such document exists")
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err.message)
        setIsLoading(false)
        setError("failed to get document")
      }
    )
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [c, id, enabled])
```

Comment: This is a great approach, Slava! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. UseEffect cannot be called conditionally
2. UseEffect is called only on the client side.

If you make minimal representation, possible to try fix this error

Comment: Could you please elaborate or add some example code?

Comment: will be easier to present your code on codepen or smth like this